# How to use tropo with node.js-socketstream framework?

Tags: node.js, socketstream, tropo

In my application im using node.js with socketstream framework.Now i need to use tropo module to send an sms,receive an sms,make a call and answering an incoming call.I installed tropo-webapi using npm.i added this node code in server side.While running the below code i didn't get any output.i dont know  how to link this file in tropo website and how to receive the sms and phone call.

```
  exports.actions = function(req, res, ss) {
  return{

sendMessage:function(){

    var tropoAPI = require('tropo-webapi');
    var tropo = new tropoAPI.TropoWebAPI(); 
  tropo.call("+18197924547", null, null, null, null, null, "SMS", null,  null,null);
        tropo.say("HI How Are You!!");

    },
makeCall:function(){

      var tropoAPI = require('tropo-webapi');
      var tropo = new tropoAPI.TropoWebAPI(); 
      tropo.call("+18197924547");
      tropo.say("Hi,how ary yoo!");

    }


};


     };
```

Answer (score 0):

So you did not specify from which file is this snippet from but I got the feeling, it is from one under `server/rpc/<yourfilename>` where the Remote Procedure Calls are.
!!! NOTE THE `<yourfilename>`

The methods which you define are generated for the client in a way that he can trigger it trough the socket interfaces, let me write a snippet, I think you will understand:
- lets write into this file => `client/code/app/app.js`

```
ss.rpc('<yourfilename>.sendMessage','here comes params which is now a string');
```

To get a sense what this `ss` object is look into your `client/code/app/entry.js` you will see it.